# Can I use claims-based authentication in SharePoint 2013 without ADFS?

Tags: 2013, claims-based-auth

Is it possible to use claims-based (Windows) authentication in SharePoint 2013 without having ADFS installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the default configuration for a web application in 2013 with plain old Active Directory is claims-based.

See these articles:

[SharePoint 2013: Claims is the new black](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-claims-is-the-new-black)

[Claims-based authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350%28v=office.15%29.aspx#cba)